# How to use`kmeans` parameter in Pillow Image.quantize?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, quantize

Doc page for `PIL.Image.quantize` gives:

```
Image.quantize(colors=256, method=None, kmeans=0, palette=None, dither=1)
    colors – The desired number of colors, <= 256
    kmeans – Integer
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize

How to use this `kmeans` parameter?

If `kmeans` is "number of clusters to use", isn't that going to be the same value as `colors`? Or is the idea to specify say 10 clusters but only 3 colors, and have the other clusters pick up the not-of-interest colors?

Comment: I think it is a *threshold* for convergence testing. So it will stop iterating if fewer than `kmeans` pixels have changed clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see in the documentation the definition you report of `kmeans` as the number of "clusters", but from my understanding the number of clusters in some cases might be larger than the number of obtained colors.

Suppose you want to reduce a greyscale image with, say, 100 unique colors (out of 256 a greyscale image can have) to 8 colors. In the case of **uniform quantization method** (which, however, is not implemented by Pillow), if those 100 colors are uniformly distributed in the (0,255) range, specifiyng 8 clusters you will probably get 8 colors, but if those 100 colors are *badly* distributed, so that there are no pixels with colors in one (or more) of the clusters, you will get a resulting image with 7 (or less) colors.

Other quantization methods make sure that clusters are not empty and so the number of colors is always the same as the number of clusters.

An overview of quantization topic [can be found here](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/%7Ematt/courses/cs563/talks/color_quant/CQindex.html).

However, I made some tests specifyng only `kmeans` parameter and I couldn't see any decrease of colors, so I guess the parameter `kmeans` isn't the number of clusters, it might be a parameter controlling clustering algorithm convergence as reported in the comment by Mark Setchell.